# ¿Como almacenar cadenas ingresadas en un arreglo y luego mostrar en consola las cadenas ingresadas?

Tags: java, array, condiciones, bucles, java-util-scanner

*Es mi primera vez usando esta plataforma de StackOverflow...

¿Como almacenar cadenas ingresadas en un arreglo y luego mostrar en consola las cadenas ingresadas?*
Tengo el problema que al mostrar la cadena que ingreso solo me muestra el último elemento ingresado en el arreglo.
Muestro mi código realizado con netbeens 12

```
//importacion de librerias  
import java.util.Scanner;  
//que nombre de la clase, que sea igual a Practica.java  
public class Practica {  
    //Principal  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        //para leer la cantidad de arreglos a leer  
        Scanner toche = new Scanner(System.in);  
        //para leer la cadena, fue necesario este 2do  
        Scanner toche2 = new Scanner(System.in);  
        //con la expectativa de que guarde todo lo que lea  
        String [] arreglo = {};

        //sale del ciclo con una condicion interna del ciclo, es decir '0'
        while(true){
            System.out.print("¿Cuantas Listas? ");//termina el ciclo digitando cero
            int lista = toche.nextInt();//¿cuantas listas?
            System.out.println("");

            if( lista != 0 ){// si es distinto de cero haga lo que sigue
                for (int i = 0; i < lista; i++) {//itera hasta que sea igual a lista
                    if( i != (lista-1)){/*nada*/}
                    else{ lista = 0;}/*estas condiciones es para asegurar que lea 'n' veces y no sea ciclo infinito*/

                    System.out.print("Ingrese Cadena #"+(i+1)+" : ");
                    String cadena = toche2.nextLine();//escriba cualquier cosa, pero separado por espacio
                    arreglo = cadena.split(" ");//¿como hacer para que se acumule todo lo que le ingresa?
                    System.out.println("La cadena "+(i+1)+" es: "+cadena+"\n");/*muestra en consola lo agregado*/
                }
                System.out.println("---\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {/*este bucle lo use para conseguir el objetivo, sin exito*/
                    System.out.println(arreglo[i]);/*muestra en pantalla lo ultimo que lee, pero no todo, es decir si leo 4 cadenas, solo muestra la ultima cadena leida*/
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Ha Terminado");
                break;//cuando se digita el cero entra a este else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

veo que tienes conceptos poco claros y tu pregunta se entiende poco, espero que sea esto lo que estabas necesitando,
Te recomiendo volver a repasar sobre todo los ciclos repetitivos mas conocidos como bucles saludos.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    boolean valor = true;

    while (valor) {
        System.out.print("¿Cuantos String agregara? ");
        Scanner toche = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cadenas = toche.nextInt();// ¿cuantas cadenass?
        System.out.println("");
        
        if (cadenas <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Ha Terminado");
            valor= false;
        } else{
            String[] arreglo = new String[cadenas];
            for (int i = 0; i < cadenas; i++) {// itera hasta que sea igual a cadenas
                System.out.print("Ingrese Cadena #" + (i + 1) + " : ");
                Scanner toche2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String cadena = toche2.nextLine();
                arreglo[i]=cadena;
            }//fin de agregar strings

            //Mostramos los string que contiene la cadenas
            for (int i=0;i<cadenas;i++){
                System.out.println("String " + (i+1) + " es: " + arreglo[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: si, siento no comunicarlo bien, digamos que faltaria añadirle el split que es lo estaba intentado, si el string que lee es por ejemplo: "julian andres gaviria mendez", haga un split, para que los vaya agregando al arreglo en palabras, "julian", "andres", "gaviria", "mendez"; si por ejemplo leo 3 cadenas nombres y apellidos, entonces recorrer el arreglo para que muestre 12 palabras que correspondes a los nombres y apellidos; seria como: arreglo [i] = cadena.split(" ");    pero de momento esta opcion no me funciona, gracias igualemente

Answer (score 0):

Veo 3 errores resaltantes en tu código:

1. No es necesario declarar más de una variable de tipo `Scanner`,
   con 1 es suficiente para leer los diferentes tipos de datos.
2. Tu validación para salir del ciclo `while` o la condicional `if`  están mal, el usuario puede tranquilamente ingresar un valor
   negativo  al solicitar la cantidad de elementos del arreglo.
3. En ninguna linea del código guardas la palabra ingresado dentro del
   arreglo.

Como último detalle, no es necesario guardar cada palabra ingresado con un espacio, si quieres mostrar cada palabra del arreglo ingresado separado por un espacio puedes hacerlo concatenando los elementos del arreglo con el espacio (" ").
Te muestro el código.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
        boolean flag = true;

        while (flag) {
            System.out.print("¿Cuantas cadenas de String desea agregar: ? ");
            Scanner toche = new Scanner(System.in);
            int cadenas = toche.nextInt();// ¿cuantas cadenas?
            System.out.println("");

            if (cadenas <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Ha Terminado");
                flag= false;
            } else{
                String[] arreglo = new String[cadenas];
                for (int i = 0; i < cadenas; i++) {// itera hasta que sea igual a cadenas
                    System.out.print("Ingrese Cadena #" + (i + 1) + " : ");
                    Scanner toche2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String cadena = toche2.nextLine();
                    arreglo[i]=cadena;
                }//fin de agregar strings

                //Mostramos los string del arreglo
                System.out.print("La cadena ingresado es: ") ;
                for (int i=0;i<cadenas;i++){
                    System.out.print(arreglo[i]+" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```